# Convert this time format "2019-02-28T08:42:57+0000" to YYYY-MM-DD format in perl

Tags: perl, date, time

I want to convert the below time format-
 "2019-02-28T08:42:57+0000" to YYYY-MM-DD format in perl

Comment: Ok, go on then. Have you given this any thought at all yet? Tried anything? Please take a look at [ask] and also take the [tour] to learn how to use Stack Overflow. We're not going to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this out:

```
use Date::Parse qw(str2time);
use Date::Format qw(time2str);

my $string = '2019-02-28T08:42:57+0000';

my $time = str2time($string);
my $date = time2str("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $time);

print $date;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Prakash. That was helpful

Comment: Hi Prakash. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for your answer. But please ensure that all answers include an explanation. At StackOverflow, we are trying to produce the highest quality and most helpful answers. [Tips Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a date module here. The format you want is contained inside the one you have. A [`substr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) is all you have to do. An ISO 8601 date is always 10 characters long, and you start at the front.

```
print substr $date, 0, 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution, in this case, (as simbabque has already pointed out) is to just treat the date as a string. As well as the `substr()` solution you've been given, you could use a regex to remove the "T" and everything following it.

```
$date =~ s/T.*$//;
```

If you really want to parse and reformat the date, then [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has been included with the standard Perl distribution since 2007.

```
use Time::Piece;

$date = '2019-02-28T08:42:57+0000';
my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z');
say $tp->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

For more complicated date and time handling (not needed here, but I'm including it for completeness) you should read for [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) and its friends.

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z',
);

my $date = '2019-02-28T08:42:57+0000';

my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime($date);

say $dt->strftime('%Y/%m/%d');
```

Answer (score 2):

With [Date::Manip](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Date-Manip/lib/Date/Manip.pod):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Date::Manip:.Date;

my $date = new Date::Manip::Date;
$date->parse("2019-02-28T08:42:57+0000")
    and die "parse" . $date->err() . "\n";

print $date->printf("%Y-%m-%d\n");

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
2019-02-28
```

**NOTE:** date and time parsing is a complex subject matter. So please

- choose an appropriate module instead of coding your own parser
- *do* study the documentation of the module you choose for the task

Comment: I remember Date::Manip to be quite heavy. Is that still the case?

Comment: @simabque no idea. But I'm not concerned by this, because it has been working flawlessly in my XMLTV screen-scraper for 10+ years...

Comment: I see. Yeah, I'm not saying it's bad. I've used it in the past too. Do prefer DateTime now for some reason.

Comment: @simbabque this [DM5 -> DM6 change document](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Date-Manip/lib/Date/Manip/Changes5to6.pod#(*)-Breaking-into-smaller-modules) may answer your question. I guess you shouldn't use `Date::Manip` anymore, but the smaller `Date::Manip::Date`. Updated my answer.

Comment: DateTime is better (in my opinion) for the huge ecosystem of parsers, formatters and other modules which all use the same underlying data model. For simpler stuff (like this problem) Time::Piece is my preferred solution as it's included with core Perl.